# How to open a web page when a Gtk.Box is clicked anywhere, in spite of the Gtk.LinkButton links inside it?

Tags: python-2.7, hyperlink, ads, gtk3, msys2

Practically, I like the style of Gtk.LinkButton and I want to use it to make an advertisement banner in my program. The label below would be a single-paragraph description of the destination of the link. But anywhere on the banner should a mouse click open the link.

This is what I tried. When I click on the `Gtk.LinkButton`, both URIs are opened. When I click elsewhere on the window, nothing is done.

**`example.py`**:

```
# coding=utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

b = Gtk.Builder()
b.add_from_file("test.glade")

w = b.get_object("window1")


def box_clicked(widget, event, user_data=None):
    del widget, event, user_data

    Gtk.show_uri_on_window(w, "http://lumea-lui-silviu.blogspot.ro",
                           Gdk.CURRENT_TIME)


linkButton = b.get_object("linkButton")
box = b.get_object("box1")
box.connect("button-release-event", box_clicked)

w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**`test.glade`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLinkButton" id="linkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="relief">none</property>
            <property name="uri">http://www.google.com</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="multilineLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">this
is
a
multiline
label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot]

Currently, I study and try some tehniques described [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2011-May/msg00071.html), but I wish someone helps me earlier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [the code modifications by José Fonte (please vote his answer too)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821685/258462), when the label is clicked, the web page is opened as expected, but when  the user clicks on the Gtk.LinkButton the web page opens twice. I solved this by setting in Glade the `above-child` property of the Gtk.EventBox to `On` and by returning `True` from the signal handler (the behavior is described in the documentation found [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.button_release_event)).

There also were some problems with the Adwaita window decorations on Windows (10). When the clickable box is the first or only child in a window, clicking on a dead zone and then moving the window triggers the opening of the web page. I solved this problem by inserting the Gtk.Box inside a Gtk.AspectFrame.

## Final example

### example.py

```
# coding=utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

b = Gtk.Builder()
b.add_from_file("test.glade")

w = b.get_object("window1")

def box_clicked(widget, event, user_data):
    #del widget, event, user_data

    # New tehnique:
    user_data.clicked()

    # Old tehnique:
    # Gtk.show_uri_on_window(w, "http://lumea-lui-silviu.blogspot.ro",
    #                        Gdk.CURRENT_TIME)

    return True

linkButton = b.get_object("linkButton")
box = b.get_object("eventbox1")
box.connect("button-release-event", box_clicked, linkButton)

w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

### test.glade

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkAspectFrame">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label_xalign">0</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEventBox" id="eventbox1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="above_child">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLinkButton" id="linkButton">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                    <property name="relief">none</property>
                    <property name="uri">http://www.google.com</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">0</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLabel" id="multilineLabel">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">this
is
a
multiline
label</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to wrap the box container inside a Gtk.EventBox. This can be done easily in Glade by right clicking the box container and choosing **Add Parent** and then **Event Box** as illustrated in the image below (*Note: the widget tree already has the event box added and that should be the result of adding the event box*):

[image: Glade add parent]

Then, eg., in the code, box should be the event box to receive the button-release-event signal and the handler can receive the LinkButton from user_data and emit the signal clicked to simulate the button click.

Adapting the code:

```
# coding=utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

b = Gtk.Builder()
b.add_from_file("test.glade")

w = b.get_object("window1")

def box_clicked(widget, event, user_data):
    user_data.clicked()
    return True

linkButton = b.get_object("linkButton")
box = b.get_object("eventbox1")
box.connect("button-release-event", box_clicked, linkButton)

w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: According to [this official documentation page](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.button_release_event) the `button-release-event` does not accept an `user_data` parameter in the slot's signature. In this line, `linkButton` is not passed theoretically: `box.connect("button-release-event", box_clicked, linkButton)`. But I tested the code and it works. #report-this-bug

Comment: @silviubogan Well that's correct. I just took your code and adapted it and since i mostly work with Gtk in C and Vala, the user_data as last argument it's always present in C but higher level languages normally take this argument to "them selfs" and use it to pass context, scope etc.

Comment: @silviubogan From the PyGObject signal [documentation](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#signals): "A generic example is: `handler_id = widget.connect("event", callback, data)` ... **Finally, the data argument includes any data which should be passed when the signal is issued. However, this argument is completely optional and can be left out if not required**."